# Can I stop Eclipse from automatically adding views?

Tags: android, eclipse, view, ide, adt

For example I have two perspectives, one for debugging, and one for coding.
In the coding area I obviously don't want views for debugging (LogCat from ADT for example).

Jet when some plugin, feature or view feels it has something important to say, it just shows up on whatever perspective I am. Eclipse just adds a view, and brings it to top everytime, which is getting quite annoying.

How do I disable this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the LogCat behavior from the Eclipse Preferences window (e.g., Window > Preferences on Windows and Linux). Go into Android > LogCat and toggle values like "Switch perspective" and "Display logcat view...".

[image]